# What can you target with Magic Missile while Blind?

Tags: dnd-4e

What can you target with Magic Missile while Blind?

<sub>Inspired by a [post](http://www.enworld.org/forum/4e-discussion/294927-magic-missile-while-blinded.html) at EnWorld.</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Anything you can target while not being blind - one creature within 20 squares, that isn't hidden from you, and that you can draw the line of effect to. Or, if you suspect something hidden, you can also target it at random squares.
Magic missile doesn't have any special rules, so you should use standard rules for "Targetting What You Can't See" (PHB1, p.281)

Comment: Great and thorough answer!